# Падежные окончания (2)

Tags: склонение, падежи, окончания

У меня возник вопрос, связанный с окончаниями по падежам.

*"Он вошел в помещени**е**."* Вошел в кого? что? помещениЕ. 2 склонение, всё сходится. *"В помещени**и** пусто."* В ком? чём? Всё то же второе склонение, по табличке окончаний по падежам должно быть "е", но все говорят (в том числе и гугл), что там "и". Как так? Чего я не понимаю? Есть слова, входящие в исключение у окончаний по падежам? И ведь много таких слов есть. Разъясните неосведомленному, пожалуйста.

Посмотрела бы в гугле информацию, да не знаю, как набрать, чтобы нужное выпало.

Comment: _Helena: по табличке окончаний по падежам должно быть "е"_ === Ссылку на _табличку_  не дадите?

Comment: https://dist-tutor.info/file.php/337/bezymjannyj_cr.jpg

Comment: Это откуда   **такое**???

Comment: На сайте Грамоты.ру выложен учебник Литневской. Посмотрите его: http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i2

Comment: Нашла другую табличку. Вот:
https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/239369439_4b5e904fdd4041a35b02cc3d6cdff817_800.jpg
Появилось ещё больше вопросов. А как по этой табличке понять: в предложном падеже в каких словах "е" писать, а в каких "и"?

Comment: Господи, ну откуда Вы это всё берёте? Ещё раз: посмотрите раздел "Склонение существительных" в учебнике Литневской по моей ссылке выше. Думаю, все вопросы у Вас отпадут.

Comment: Видимо, я настолько дуб, что не могу найти в учебнике нужное. Именно этот раздел прочла, но ответа на свои вопросы так и не нашла. Если можно, вырежете из учебника ответы и напишите здесь, в ответе на вопрос, что да как. Буду очень благодарна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helena, вам уже дали "правильную" табличку, но прямо не сказали главного.

Не все существительные относятся к трем "школьным" типам склонения.
Существительные с окончанием -ий, -ия, -ие (мужского, женского и среднего рода соответственно) по школьной систематике **не относятся** к трем основным типам склонения. Здесь отличий немного, но они есть.

Cмотрите:
И калий, гений, Василий; армия, Мария; зрение
Р калия, гения, Василия; арм**ии**, Мари**и**; зрения
Д калию, гению, Василию; арм**ии**, Мар**ии**; зрению
В калий, гения, Василия; армию, Марию; зрение
Т калием, гением, Василием; армией, Марией; зрением
П (о) кал**ии**, ген**ии**, Васил**ии**; арм**ии**, Мар**ии**; зрен**ии**

Выделены случаи безоговорочных отличий от основных типов склонения, остальные формы более или менее совпадают (с оговоркой на чтение Я, Е, Ю в позиции после гласной).

Видно, что предложный падеж отличается у всех родов. При этом у односложных существительных м.р. (кий, змий, Вий) наблюдаются колебания в выборе варианта ("о кие" или "о кии"?).

Существительные, бывшие когда-то прилагательными (так называемые "субстантивированные прилагательные"), тоже обычно имеют окончания -ия, -ий, -ие, но склоняются обычно как прилагательные.

Кроме того, есть еще некоторое число существительных, которые склоняются по совсем уж необычным схемам (путь, дитя, время, вымя, семя, мать, дочь - и т. д.) они никак не могут быть отнесены к основным трем "школьным" типам. Их изменения по падежам надо смотреть по словарям и грамматикам.

К сожалению в школьной практике преподавания русского языка сплошь и рядом встречается ситуация, когда привило (или вот такая табличка) для первичного ознакомления приводится как некий абсолют, о существовании исключений даже не упоминается. Порекомендовать могу только одно. Прежде чем следовать какой-либо инструкции, поинтересуйтесь, а нет ли на неё исключений. Это не только к русской грамматике относится.

Comment: Не смею "влезать", но надо бы ещё окончания в Р. и В. падежах подправить.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Уже.))) Спасибо, вы меня как раз в процессе поймали. А вообще - не стесняйтесь, очевидные опечатки правьте смело. Я сейчас вообще не в лучшей форме, не хватает сил сразу вычитать, если сравнительно большой текст.

Comment: Васеньку-то пропустили! И _Марияж_.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова ОК, еще раз спасибо. Дальше, коли найдете еще что, то  берите уже инициативу в свои руки, я на отдых до вечера.

Comment: @Мимоходов: _Существительные с окончанием -ий, -ия, -ие (мужского, женского и среднего рода соответственно) по школьной систематике  **не относятся** к трем основным типам склонения._ === ??? И к камим же типам склонения, по-вашему, относятся эти существительные  **по школьной систематике**?  Хоть **один** какой-нибудь школьный учебник или справочник сможете привести в подтверждение своих слов?

Comment: @slava1947 в мои годы их относили к "особому склонению" - и то уже классе в седьмом. А до того их вообще не упоминали. А вот подтверждать, простите,  ваша задача. А то вы хорошо устроились. Докажите, типа, что Бога нет.

Comment: Гм... Подтверждать Ваши слова -- **моя** задача??? Подтвердить я могу свои слова -- ссылками на учебники. А вот Ваши... постараюсь опровергнуть. В комментарии места мне не хватит, придётся  дополнять свой ответ. Но сделаю это, наверное, только завтра -- с глазами проблема...

Comment: @slava1947 я все-таки полагаюсь на вашу вменяемость. **Вы реально утверждаете, что есть учебники, где бы эти слова относили к одному (или нескольким) основным "школьным" склонениям?!** Именно так, без оговорок?! И готовы это подтвердить? Мне жалко Ваши глаза, просто вдумайтесь в смысл того, что вы сейчас взялись доказывать, иначе ваш труд будет воистину сизифовым.

Comment: @Мимоходов, простите, а что Вы называете основными "школьными" склонениями? Первое, второе, третье склонение или что-либо ещё? Я могу попытаться привести выдержки из учебных пособий, по которым учились школьники и 10, и 20, и 60 с лишним лет назад, в которых приведённые в Вашем ответе слова -- не относящиеся, по Вашему мнению, "по школьной систематике к трем основным типам склонения" -- всё-таки распределялись между этими тремя группами. Этого Вам будет недостаточно?

Comment: *Первое, второе, третье склонение* - именно так. Вообще это идет от того, что в академической практике "первым" склонением называют то, что в школе - вторым и наоборот. Но это чисто терминологический вопрос, тут и спорить нечего. Вот сложнее с самим понятием "склонения". *Я могу попытаться привести выдержки из учебных пособий* - достаточно в принципе одной, но где было бы четко сказано, что эти слова склонятся точно так же, как и остальные, входящие в эти основные типы. Понятно, что такой учебник надо автоматически отправлять в печку.

Comment: А вот как на самом деле поступают. Популярный учебник Ладыженской. http://vklasse.org/5-klass/uchebniki/russkij-yazyk/ta-ladyzhenskaya-mt-baranov-la-trostentsova-2012-chast-1  в п. 94 дается распределение по групам, и только в п. 96 появляется оговорка, признающая (да и то косвенно), что эти слова на -ий, -ие, -ия не относятся к указанным типам. И это хорошо еще что это недалеко от исходного "правила". В пособиях, которым изначально оперировала Helena их, оговорок, видимо нет вообще. Или они где-то очень далеко. И вот вам результат.

Comment: @Мимоходов: _В пособиях, которым изначально оперировала Helena их, оговорок, видимо нет вообще._ === Да бросьте!.. Всё, уверен, в них есть. Только "Helena" – сознательно или бессознательно (скорее первое) – их не привела. Как не привела и названий этих пособий…

Comment: @slava1947 *Да бросьте!* С чего бы? Я вам Лодыженскую привел в пример. Напутал немного с цифрами параграфов (там 96 и 99 должно быть), но это не принципиально, главное, что правило дается *без оговорок*. А оговорки появляются в лучшем случае - много после.  Вот еше Бархударова нашел в сети, мы оба по нему учились, как я понимаю. $42 - стр. 85. -ий, -ие, -ия даже не упоминаются. https://sheba.spb.ru/shkola/ru-56-1962.htm

Comment: Тут целый спор, как погляжу. Сама решила поискать, что от чего пошло. Вообще, до вот этого вопроса я особо не задумывалась, с каким окончанием писать "в помещении", "в здании" и прочее. Просто смотрела в вики, какое у них окончание в предложном падеже. Но, распечатав табличку с окончаниями в первом и втором склонении только "е" в предложном падеже, столкнулась с целым рядом сложностей и непонимания.

Comment: Нарыла в интернете такую информацию:

"Второй предложный падеж, или местный падеж — оригинальная (беспредложная) форма местного падежа практически полностью утрачена и перешла в формы предложного и творительного, однако у некоторых существительных грамматически отличная форма предложного падежа: в лесу, в тени́."

Comment: Книга "Грамматический метод обучения русскому правописанию. Книга 1. Лекции по орфографии" автора Наталии Киреевой. Тема 3, параграф 2 "окончания существительных с основой на ия, ие, ий, ея, ье, ья". Ссылка на скрин листа книги, не на неё саму: 
https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2018/07/aa7098786e38e1d2a135323b9f1dfb4b.png

Comment: @Helena *Нарыла в интернете такую информацию* есть такая форма, да. Но она никакого отношения к склонению существительніх на -ий, -ия, -ие не имеет. Вы все запутали... У этих слов (в тени, в крови, в шерсти) местная форма предложного отличается от общей   (собственно предложной или пропозициональной) формы только ударением. Окончание И присутствует в обоих случаях.

Comment: Это то? 

"Существительные, оканчивающиеся на -ия (армия, се­рия, линия, Мария) образуют особый вариант склонения, в формах родительного, дательного и предложного падежей имеют окончание -и:"

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/140-pravopisanieokonchaniyimensucshestvitelnyh.html

Comment: @Мимоходов 9 часов назад: Вот еше Бархударова нашел в сети, мы оба по нему учились, как я понимаю. $42 - стр. 85. -ий, -ие, -ия даже не упоминаются. ===  **Вы не правы!** У Бархударова на стр. 85 всё чётко расписано! См.: _"К первому склонению относятся… арм**ия**"; "Ко второму склонению относятся… пролетар**ий**… здан**ие**"_.

Answer (score 2):

См. раздел "Склонение существительных" в [**учебнике Литневской**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i2):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на склонение существительного ***пение***.

Comment: Это я видела, но так и не поняла. Тут я могу также в предложном падеже в "в помещениЕ" это самое "е" пихнуть, когда нужно "и". Вот "окно", например, - это моё. "В окнЕ" - "е" ведь ставится. 2 склонение, предложный падеж, средний род. Но почему тогда "в помещении" ставится "и"? Тоже ведь 2 склонение, предложный падеж, средний род.

Comment: Да, тоже второе склонение. Но окончание в им. падеже не "-ие". Слово же "помещение" имеет окончание "-ие", такое же, как и слово "пение". Вот по образцу склонения слова "пение" и нужно склонять "помещение" (см. последний столбец в таблице).

Answer (score 0):

Кажись, поняла. На всякий случай более ясно лично для себя отвечу на свой же вопрос.

*"В помещении"*. Средний род, второе склонение, окончание "ие" (помещение). В предложном падеже ставится окончание "ии".

Ещё примеры.

*"В склонении"*, *"Во введении"*. Средний род, второе склонение, окончание "ие" (склонение, введение). В предложном падеже ставится окончание "ии".

То есть, выходит, у всех слов среднего рода с окончанием "ие" в предложном падеже ставится окончание "ии".